# ASP.NET MVC - Stop Html.TextBoxFor adding a dot to the Name attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and I've got a problem with Html.TextBoxFor() - it's giving the rendered input's *name* attribute a dot.

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Box.Name, new { id= "txtName" }) %>
```

renders the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Box.Name" id="txtName">
```

I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin for client-side validation. It can't validate this input because of the dot in *Box.Name* (causes a javascript error).

My Model looks like this:

```
public class Box {
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int BoxMaterialID { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class BoxViewModel
{
    public Box Box { get; set; }
    public List<BoxMaterial> BoxMaterial { get; set;}
}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult New(FormCollection postData)
{
    Box box = new Box();

    try
    {
        UpdateModel(box, "Box");
        boxService.SaveBox(box);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(new BoxViewModel(box));
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Boxes");
}
```

Server-side validation is working like a charm using DataAnnotations on the Model. The only problem I seem to be having is with the client-side validation because of the "." in the name attribute.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dot added to the name is used by the [default model binder](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) when the form is submitted in order to correctly populate the model. As far as validation is concerned you could set it like this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        'Box.Name': {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'Box.Name': {
            required: 'some error message'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Darin. Looks like I need to better understand model binding. Adding quotes to the name did the trick and now client-side validation is working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the name attribute as well:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Box.Name, new { id= "txtName", name = "txtName" }) %>
```

Comment: I tried this and the name attribute was still set to 'Box.Name'. Thanks for the suggestion though.